# BindingResult argument in spring boot not working

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to catch the errors in a @RestController.

I present the model I am playing with:

```
    public class CreateUpdateTodoDto {
         private Long userId;

         @NotNull(message = "The TODO title must not be null")
         @Size(min=1, max=3, message = "Title size too large, maximum < 4")
         private String title;

         @NotNull
         private boolean completed;

    }
```

I present the RestController

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody @Valid CreateUpdateTodoDto dto, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new TodoConstrainValidationException(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(todoService.insert(dto));

    }


    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody @Valid CreateUpdateTodoDto dto,
                                    @PathVariable("id") int id,
                                    HttpServletRequest request,
                                    BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new TodoConstrainValidationException(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(todoService.update(dto, id, request));

    }
```

In the insert method, if I send an invalid object, it detects it correctly and throws the exception as I expect, all correct for me.
The problem comes with the put method, if I send an invalid object, I simply receive a response with the empty body and with status 400, now if I remove the parameters **@PathVariable ("id") int id**, and **HttpServletRequest request**, it works as it should to be. Because if you have these two parameters (int id and HttpServletRequest request), it doesn't work the same way?
I leave you the photos of the responses I get with Postman.

For me it is correct, it is what is expected (within my ignorance)
[image]

Here I am already lost, I could eliminate the 2 parameters that I have commented previously and it would work, but I don't know why it acts this way.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters order important the `BindingResult` need to come after the request body that you are doing validation. Modify `PuttMapping` as below.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody @Valid 
CreateUpdateTodoDto dto, BindingResult bindingResult,
                                @PathVariable("id") int id,
                                HttpServletRequest request )
```